# Anyone else having problems with Chrome today? 08/04/2014

Tags: jquery, html, google-chrome, slider, updates

I am having a strange problem with chrome.

All my inputs (type range) are not sending values when moving the slider anymore however, the value is updated just when the mousebutton is realised.

here a simple example of a slider used to update the frequency value of an oscillator.

http://jsfiddle.net/salvonostrato/aL9jg/

It was working fine 5 hours ago as all my other apps. I did not changed anything and in Safari it works just fine.

I am using a simple jquery change function to update the value.

```
$('#slider').change(function () {

console.log ($("#slider").val());

oscillator.frequency.value = $("#slider").val();
document.getElementById('freq').value = $("#slider").val();


});
```

Is it something I have to worry about and change all my projects, or is just because Chrome team is updating the servers or libraries??

thanks

Comment: did you update chrome recently?

Comment: nope. Does it work in your browser? I have also tested on another laptop and its not working anymore

Comment: It worked in my browser before i updated, but not after. So, yes, a recent update in chrome seems to have changed that functionality. i went from 33.x to 34.0.1847.116 m

Comment: But I am sure I haven't done any updates on both laptops. I went out got back and now its not working ... Cannot understand that

Comment: Closing google chrome automatically updates it (wish all browsers worked that way)

Comment: Version 34.0.1847.116
 
Google Chrome is up to date.  It updated by itself!!!

Comment: And Now? how can I get that functionality back?

Comment: use the input event. :)

Comment: how can i do that? I think I am using it already <input type="range"> no?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/aL9jg/2/

Comment: Thank everyone, I still don't understand why they have done that. Now i have to change all my inputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it looks like a recent update to chrome changed the `change` event to only trigger when you stop moving the handle. Fortunately you can still use the input event.

```
$('#slider').on("input change", function () {
    console.log($("#slider").val());
    oscillator.frequency.value = $("#slider").val();
    document.getElementById('freq').value = $("#slider").val();
});
```

i left "change" there for backward compatibility with browsers that don't support `input`, though since you're using a webkit interface, it's likely safe to just use input.

http://jsfiddle.net/aL9jg/2/